# Mysql query able to rank products by best matching colors

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that filter products by categories, price and colors.
I'm not able to find a way to order results by best matching colors, so that products that match more with rgb(35,44,65) stay on top of results.
Any idea?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.id_product), p.*, pn.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id_product=pc.id_product 
INNER JOIN product_names pn ON p.id_product=pn.id_product 
WHERE 
(id_category IN (10,20) OR id_category IN (10,40)) 
and price<=3500 
and p.id_product IN (SELECT DISTINCT(id_product) FROM colors ORDER BY (POW(35-red, 2)+POW(44-green, 2)+POW(65-blue, 2)) ASC) 
GROUP BY p.id_product 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_category) = 2
```

Comment: please always provide a [mre] and read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: FYI, `DISTINCT` is not a function. It applies to the entire `SELECT` list, not a specific column in parentheses.

Comment: And if you use `GROUP BY `p.id_product`, it's guaranteed to be distinct.

Comment: you should put `ORDER BY` in the main query, not the subquery.

Comment: `(id_category IN (10,20) OR id_category IN (10,40))` is the same as `id_category IN (10, 20, 40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join with the `colors` table rather than using `IN`. Then you can get the color values to use in `ORDER BY` in the main query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, pn.*
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id_product=pc.id_product 
INNER JOIN product_names pn ON p.id_product=pn.id_product 
INNER JOIN colors AS c ON c.id_product = p.id_product
WHERE pc.id_category IN (10, 20, 40)
AND p.price <= 3500
GROUP BY p.id_product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_category) = 2
ORDER BY (POW(35-c.red, 2)+POW(44-c.green, 2)+POW(65-c.blue, 2)) ASC
```